# krdc : trouble with images and videos

Tags: raspbian, remote, rdp, desktop

I use krdc on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2 for a long time now. I use krdc to connect my raspberry to my windows Server 2008. But the display of images and videos are too slow. Do you know why? I have an adsl connection of 10Mbits synchronous. My server is in Belgium and my Raspberry Pi 3 is in Senegal. How can I do to resolve that?

Comment: Somebody can help me ?

Comment: My version of krdc (4:16.08.3-1). My Raspbian version is Stretch 9.1